# What sort of 'faction system' could be established in a world where social order has broken down?

Tags: magic, government, dystopia

Think of dystopian fiction such as the Divergent series, where almost all social order has broken down across America due to war.

Any ideas or basis to start with that aren't going to be exactly the same as Divergent?

Comment: Welcome to the site Lexo.  As it stands this question is far too broad and is essentially idea generation which makes it off topic for the site.  In this scenario you can either set up a scenario and ask what is the most likely outcome or you can propose an idea and ask if it is plausible.  Please provide either a significantly more detailed scenario or propose a solution and the scenario and ask about plausibility.

Comment: The same as what? Dictatorship? Theocracy? Democracy? Tribal?

Comment: They are starting from scratch, they can have whatever government they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these future dystopias were designed to be allegorical; the existence and structure of the world teaches the reader a lesson about how *not* to run a human society.

The most obvious is *Divergent*'s, with its faction system; teenagers are separated from each other based on testing that determines their most dominant desirable trait out of 5; intelligence, fearlessness, friendliness, honesty, or selflessness. The catch is that any person who's evenly balanced between two or more of these traits is a danger to that very system (exactly why is never really explained, but the answer turns out to be that "divergents" can't be predicted or controlled because they don't think the same way as those who fit in, which - SPOILER ALERT - turns out to be exactly what the system was intended to produce).

The world of *The Hunger Games* is slightly more subtle, but it was modeled pretty much directly on the Roman Empire; a single nation-state maintaining a fragile "peace through power" among outlying areas under the pretense of protecting them from their enemies and preserving the last remnants of human civilization, but really the main enemy in the eyes of most of the governed is Rome itself. In fact, the name of the nation, "Panem", originally sounds like some evolution of "Pan-Am" relating to the North American geographic setting, but it's explained (and savvy readers already know) that the term is a play on the Latin phrase "panem et circenses" (lit. "bread and circuses"), used by Latin satirist Juvenal to describe the blind obedience of Roman citizens to the varying whims of Caesar, as long as they were fed and entertained. This is illustrated many times in the books with the behavior of the average Capitol citizen, so inured and sheltered in their wealth and privilege that they can't seem to empathize with the kids in the arena on any deeper level than characters in a drama.

There are other stories as well; Orwell, a civil libertarian thinker, sought to warn against the dangers of the extremes of socialism in *1984* by portraying an all-knowing, all-seeing police state government in Great Britain (much the same society and imagery formed the backdrop for the *V for Vendetta* graphic novel and film). *Animal Farm*, in a similar vein, was a more direct allegory of post-1917 Russia under first Lenin, then Stalin. *A Clockwork Orange* is also similar, essentially a police state in which thought control and Pavlovian conditioning are employed to control society. *Soylent Green* paints a very dark picture of an overpopulated, destitute Earth where the masses are forced into cities and survive on highly-processed wafers which, as it turns out, is made by euthanizing people and processing their bodies.

Other dystopias merely serve as the backdrop of the more up-front story; one could argue that the Pixar movie *WALL-E* is about as dystopic as you could get in a G-rated film. The Earth is covered in garbage, polluted beyond habitability, and its sole remaining inhabitant is a robot programmed to clean it up. Meanwhile, the humans have escaped to space and are in the 700th year of a National Lampoon style cruise from hell, spending their daily lives in front of a screen talking remotely to the person right next to them (sound familiar?), with a sentient autopilot directed to maintain the status quo at all costs.

---

So, there's some meta-storytelling at play in most of these dystopias. The answer to your question, then, hinges on the story you want to tell and what message you want to give your readers, if any. In creating a dystopia, it will be hard to avoid allegory, as you'll have some explaining to do and the easiest place to start is to take a present-day system of government and make something go horribly wrong. You can choose to dwell on that and make it a part of the message you want to give the audience, or you can let it simply be a backdrop that puts characters in a place, situation and mindset that you need them to be in for your story.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the books you reference, the dystopian government is not the outcome of an apocalypse (although some of the dystopias have deliberately *created* an apocalypse like setting. 1984's permanent state of war can be considered such).

The real issue with an apocalypse is the destruction of both the pre existing social order, as well as the institutions that underlay it. (notably the technology does not have to be destroyed with the institutions, although without a strong sort of market economy to incentives innovation, dystopias usually become stagnant in technological innovation as well).

Since the social order and structure has been eliminated, generally things will devolve to whoever is the strongest and can impose their own social or political order on the chaos. In history, this is sometimes known as the arrival of the "Man on the white horse" (after a famous painting of Napoleon). Most people crave order and stability in order to carry out the day to day activities needed just to survive and raise a family, so it is not too surprising that when "the man on the white horse" arrives and promises stability, people will eagerly flock to him, without considering what sort of long term deal they have just signed up for (think of Napoleon, Lenin and the Bolsheviks or even the Taliban after the Russians left Afghanistan. In all cases they promised "order", but many people came to regret the sort of "order" that came with the ascent of these new entities).